# Python - unit testing class that extracts data from html pages

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing small application in Python and one module is responsible for downloading and parsing web pages using `Beautiful Soup` for parsing and `urllib2` for page downloading.

I am wondering now, how could I write unit tests for the class responsible for parsing the pages.

I could create some abstraction around `urllib2` and inject it to the classes that are responsible for parsing (my plan is to have different classes for different webpages) and during testing I would inject an object that will mock this abstraction. But I am not so sure about this way. I would only create an abstraction because it will be easier to write the tests not because the abstraction is needed (at least that is what I think for now).

Also I would then have a problem how to test this abstraction, it would need internet connection to work properly and when I would run the tests how could I assert that the proper page was downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement unit tests in python, you should consider using Mocks and patches:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/

Comment: I know about mocking, I even mentioned it in my post. My problem is that I don't know how can I properly test my class that uses function `urlopen` from `urllib2` for downloading pages. Even if I create an abstraction around page downloading there is still a case of testing this abstraction and we have the same problem again.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. You do not need to create the abstraction by yourself to mock  `urlopen`, you can use the patch decorator.